# Couch DB _attachment shows up in response, can't access it in code

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I have a couchapp. I have a view where i called include_docs. in the network tab where i can see the response from the server, i can see the `_attachment` object filled with data. But when i console.log the `data` in the call back it shows `null`. All other objects in the `doc` are as it is. Only `_attachment` is having problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [InLine Attachments](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Inline_Attachments) you'll can see that the `_attachments` element of the document will return have `doc.stub === true` within the document.  You need to do a separate request for the attachments you would like, `GET /database/attachment_doc/foo.txt` (from their example).